# Callback API to URL

Tags: api, google-apps-script, curl, post, get

I am new to using APIs. The documentation says that they will POST XML information in an URL.
I have created a google site in order for the API to send this information.
Is the google site able to receive this XML POST?
How do I retrieve this information from the site?

Thanks

Comment: Short answer Google Sites no, Google Apps Script web app yes.. For further details please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function doPost(e) {
  const content = e.postData.getDataAsString();
  console.log(content);
  const xml = XmlService.parse(content);
  const root = xml.getRootElement();
  /* ... */
}
```

References:

[Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

[Deploy a script as a web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app)

[XML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service)

Comment: Thank you for the code @idfurw
How do I read the XML file?

So the API sends a POST. How do I read that information?

Comment: The third reference has a clear example. Please read.